# How this Set and Hashset and List combination working?

Tags: java, collections, set, hashset

Can anyone please explain this code to me, I don't have much coding experience with `Collections` so I am having difficulties in understanding these LOC.

```
String[] stringList ={"1","2","1","1","2","3","2","3","2","1"}; 
List<String> al =Arrays.asList(stringList); 
Set<String> uniqueList = new HashSet<String>(al); 
for (String strCount :uniqueList) { 
     System.out.println(strCount + ": " + Collections.frequency(al, strCount)); 
}
```

Why does this loop only run 3 times while `uniquelist` has all the members of `stringList`. Shouldn't the loop run 10 times (length of `uniqueList`)?

Comment: You can check the size of set uniqueList by invoking the size() method on it.

Comment: May I suggest naming your variables a little better? For example, you are naming a set as uniqueList. A better variable name would convey that it is a set.

Comment: Thank you Atul but now this post already got too many anwers , so if I change the name now , users will get confused if anyone seeks help from this page in future.

Comment: @Sobia I think Atul meant that you should change the variable names in your code, not here in the question.

Comment: yes, I meant it as a general practice... not in this question as such. :)

Comment: Ohhh .. it is just a dummy code , don't worry :)) .. Thanks everyone here for helping me out in understanding this code... Cheers!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The for loop only executes three times, because there are only 3 distinct values in your `stringList`.

A [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) does not allow duplicate entries. The `Set` checks entries with `.equals()`, which will be `true` for two duplicate entries. Consequently, there are only three elements in `uniqueList`, namely: `"1"`, `"2"` and `"3"`.

Note, that `"2".equals("2")` is `true`.

Here is the most important part of the javadoc:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements `e1` and `e2` such that `e1.equals(e2)`, and at most one null element.

Answer (score 7):

A `Set` is a `Collection` that contains no duplicate element. Since your array contains only 1, 2 and 3 as unique elements, your Set will contain only 3 elements.

Check this documentation [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Answer (score 4):

> why this loop runs only 3 times while "uniquelist" has all the members
>   of "StringList"

**No it doesn't**.

If you go with general **`Mathematical`** definition of a `Set`, a **Set** is collection of `unique` values. They can't have duplicate.

Same follows in Java also (In fact anywhere), so when you convert your `List` to a `Set`, all the `Duplicate` values are `filtered out`. Only `unique` values are retained.

Answer (score 4):

according to [java spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29):

add method in HashSet implementation:

> public boolean add(E e)
>
> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.
>   More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set
>   contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)).
>   If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
>   unchanged and returns false.

Answer (score 4):

```
Set<String> uniqueList = new HashSet<String>(al);
```

As `Set` does not allow duplicates, hence after executing this statement the 
`uniqueList` contains the elements `"1"`, `"2"` and `"3"`.